# Precise Pangolin (12.04) trying to install Trusty Tahr (14.04) updates?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository, partial-upgrade

Today the Upadate Manager has begun to ask me to install these ("Important Security") updates:

- Generic Linux kernel headers
  linux-headers-generic-lts-trusty (Size: 3 kB)
- Generic Linux kernel image
  linux-image-generic-lts-trusty (Size: 3 kB)
- Transitional package for nvidia-331
  nvidia-331 (Size: 5 kB)

The problem is they are greyed out and I get the error message:

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

**Not all updates can be installed**

Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible.

This can be caused by:

- A previous upgrade which didn't complete
- Problems with some of the installed software
- Inofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
- Normal changes of a pre-release version of Ubuntu

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

I've search on Internet and I've seen many people solve similar problems executing the partial upgrade, but more than install them I would like to know **why is this Precise Pangolin (12.04) trying to install Trusty Tahr (14.04) packages**.

I've checked the repositories and there is no one referring to the Trusty release, so, What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages are not from the Trusty archive. They are from the Precise archive. The kernel packages are backported from the newer releases, for hardware enablement. If you installed from a point release of Precise (12.04.5 for example), then you likely are already using such a kernel.